# Parsing json with multiple dimension array values using jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i want to parse the json values using jquery,i cannot get  all the values using $.each but i can able to get the key.i dont know how to parse this values.the following code is used in my project.so following is json which i need to parse it.

```
{
    "0": {
        "Date": "2013-09-05 03:56:30"
    },
    "1": {
        "City": {
            "id": "1",
            "country_id": "1",
            "cityname": "Mumbai",
            "city_urlname": "mumbai",
            "lat": "19.0759837",
            "long": "72.87765590000004",
            "status": "enable",
            "flag": "0",
            "created_on": "2013-09-04 22:02:42"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "City": {
            "id": "2",
            "country_id": "1",
            "cityname": "Chennai",
            "city_urlname": "chennai",
            "lat": "13.0524139",
            "long": "80.25082459999999",
            "status": "enable",
            "flag": "0",
            "created_on": "2013-09-04 00:53:54"
        }
    },
    "33": {
        "Category": {
            "id": "1",
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "dream",
            "category_urlname": "culture",
            "lft": "1",
            "rght": "2",
            "created_on": "2013-08-13 05:51:04",
            "status": "enable",
            "flag": "0"
        }
    },
    "34": {
        "Category": {
            "id": "2",
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "Education",
            "category_urlname": "education",
            "lft": "3",
            "rght": "4",
            "created_on": "2013-08-13 05:51:23",
            "status": "enable",
            "flag": "0"
        }
    },
    "35": {
        "Category": {
            "id": "3",
            "parent_id": null,
            "name": "Marketing",
            "category_urlname": "marketing",
            "lft": "5",
            "rght": "6",
            "created_on": "2013-08-13 05:51:51",
            "status": "enable",
            "flag": "0"
        }
    }
}


$.getJSON("http://demourl/something?date=0000-00-00",function(data){

                                     $.each(data, function(i,value){
                                          alert(i);
                                          alert("city"+value.City.id);-->i cannot get the city or category values
                                            });




                                     });
```

Comment: what do you get in the alert?

Comment: hi, in alert(i) i get 0,1,2,33(with out second alert i can get all key else  first alert 0 only get and rest of the values did not shown in alert) and so on/but in the second alert nothing i get even undefined

Comment: You even don't need Jquery to parse json. Use json2 for Ie7,8 and in other browser Json.Parse will work without any library

Comment: tried firebug autocomplte in Firebug to do it fast

Comment: its a phonegap app so i did not use browser to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't tell enough but if you try this you'll get an idea

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    if('Date' in v) console.log('Date : ' + v.Date);
    if('Category' in v) console.log('Category : ' + v.Category.name);
    if('City' in v) console.log('City : ' + v.City.cityname);
});
```

[**Check this Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkqNr/1/)

Comment: hi sir thanks for your valuabel answer but i have one doubt according to my code  in console.log(value.category.id)  instead you put console.log('Category : ' + v.Category.name); so why i cannt..

Comment: You are welcome dear and we all are developers here, `each one teach one` is the way, so no sir :-)

Comment: It's just to make it clear to you which one is printing so you can remove/modify the code according to your need.